# How to get the GRUB using virtualbox?

Tags: grub2, kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I have ubuntu-12.04 on my virtualbox and I have two kernels in /boot (old and new). When I restart the vbox no grub appears to choose! and the result of `cat /proc/cmdline` still shows the old kernel is running.

I tried pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> but it also does not work!

Comment: Alternatively, comment `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`, per http://askubuntu.com/a/16049

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to know that VirtualBox is just Virtual, so many things can be different.

Reboot your virtual machine and when you see Oracle's logo , click the screen (focus there) and then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> until Grub menu appears.

Comment: Wow thank you so much it took so much of my time and now it works:)

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And add a `#` in front of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Finally, apply with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Credits: https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/263353

Note: If you plan to [change GRUB2 shell keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/a/751260/263353), forget immediately about using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> method. It may be normal that `terminal_input at_keyboard` make this key not work anymore.