# How to change grub command-line (grub shell) keyboard layout?

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, keyboard-layout

When I boot in GRUB2 and press <kbd>c</kbd>, I have access to GRUB shell.

How to change the keyboard layout (language) of this GRUB shell?

Note that I'm booting an Ubuntu VM inside Virtualbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, check that you're using GRUB 2 (GRUB 0.x works differently).

```
grub-install --version
```

Generate a GRUB keyboard layout file. Below is the command for a `fr`ench keyboard. For other languages, check `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. Filename choice is not important (you can change `bepo`).

```
sudo grub-kbdcomp -o /boot/grub/bepo.gkb fr
```

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with root rights to have:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="at_keyboard"
```

Edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` with root rights to have:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

insmod keylayouts
keymap /boot/grub/bepo.gkb
```

Finally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Note: **Forget immediately about using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>** key to display GRUB menu! It may be normal that `terminal_input at_keyboard` make this key not work anymore. So make sure `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` is properly commented.

Comment: Trying this on Linux Mint 18.3 with german locale (de) completely disabled my keyboard while in grub. Probably because `grub-kbdcomp` reported multiple times `invalid code` and `invalid identifier`

Comment: Link is dead and solution isn't bullet proof on laptops.

Comment: Will this work as well for decrypting passphrase typing (full disk encryption including `/boot`)?

Answer (score 2):

Fine-tuning my grub (2.02-2ubuntu8.3), on an old fully functional Asus N73JF (multiboot Windows 7, Windows recovery, Ubuntu 15.10, Ubuntu 18.04...) a custom menu was not an option for me.

```
sudo grub-kbdcomp -o /boot/grub/layouts/laptop.gkb fr
```

(Ubuntu's grub2 uses /boot/grub/layouts from 15.10).

Next, I don't open `/etc/default/grub` nor `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`: I edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header` where I replace

```
    cat << EOF
  set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
EOF
```

with

```
    cat << EOF
  set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod terminal
  terminal_output gfxterm
  insmod keylayouts
  insmod at_keyboard
  terminal_input at_keyboard
  keymap laptop
EOF
```

Thanks to KrisWebDev for his question-answer: I learn a lot looking inside `/boot/grub/i386-pc/`.

Comment: I do not have /boot/grub/layouts in Ubuntu 20.04. /boot/grub/i386-pc/ has only binary .mod files. What do you learn from those?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it!

If anyone should try this on a **notebook** / **laptop**, don't! Like [Zulgrib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout#comment1672660_751260) said in hirs comment this isn't bulletproof, i.a.it can wreak your grub boot-loader.

The German Debian Forum doesn't recommend it either!

> This only works if a keyboard is connected that can be addressed with
> AT or USB. A laptop or notebook keyboard may not work at all and
> leaves you sitting in front of an unusable GRUB2! In any case, the
> keyboard of the Lenovo X220 does not work.

[German Debian Forum](https://debianforum-de.translate.goog/forum/viewtopic.php?t=169882&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

Comment: This is not an answer and this is an English only site.

Comment: The content of the page I linked to translates to English if you click it.

Comment: I confirm DHC19's quote. While it works fine in a VM, it doesn't work on both my laptops. Does anybody know a way to change GRUB's keyboard layout on a laptop ?

Answer (score 0):

Comment on comment of jamo to 2nd answer:
You can create  /boot/grub/layouts manually.

```
sudo mkdir /boot/grub/layouts
```