# How to change keyboard layout on Bootup?

Tags: grub2, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After new Update, I'm getting error when I try to unlock my disk:

```
Warning: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
Please unlock disk sda3_crypt HERE I HIT PASSWORD

cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?
```

After long search on forums, I supposed it's problem with keyboard layout, probably when I installed ubuntu I wrote password with UK layout and now after Update, layout was changed to US and I don't know how can I change to UK, maybe there are some commands in GRUB2.

Comment: When you say English layout do you mean UK layout? If so, there's only one major difference from the US layout, the @ and the ' sign are reversed.

Comment: @ToDo if it so, can I reinstall ubuntu again from scratch if disk is encrypted ?

Comment: You can, but you'll loose the contents of the encrypted partition if you are not cautious (!).

Comment: Also, if your `/boot` partition is *not* encrypted, then you should be able to change your keyboard layout from the grub CLI. See here for a starter: https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue wit a cached keyboard `kmap.gz`.
My solution was:

- load Ubuntu live from USB: I loaded Ubuntu 19, but 18.04 will work too
- start Ubuntu disks
- you will see the encrypted disk.
- select it
- in the settings menu, there is an option to change the key
- click it
- you will be asked for the current password and for type two times the new password

That's all.   Reboot and use the new password.

Advice: use a digits combination always in a view to avoid such issues.