# How to change core booting language of Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, nvme, system-language

I just got stucked - I have nvme encrypted disk with my ubuntu 18.06 and after updating core (5.3.0-28-generic) I can't input password for uncryption correctly. 
The problem is that core loading with RU language(I have ru and eng languages in my system), not standard eng. And default language switching shortcuts doesnt work (super+space). So, I understand that I need to change language at booting options, but I don't know how.
P.S- I had problems with language before (mistakes with setxbmap were made) but I resolved it with resetting system settings to default.

Comment: do you mean at the grub prompt? https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout

Comment: `lsb_release -rd` please, there is no release 18.06.